# Cannot resolve/understand "overriding virtual function differs only by calling convention"

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I currently had a pending [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446855/c-sharp-managed-dll-and-native-c-is-it-possible-to-call-consumer-methods-thr) open - however after working on it I ran onto a new problem and the errors that I was getting while attempting to build it were:

```
Error   1   error C2695: 'MyEventsSink::OnSomethingHappened': overriding virtual function differs from 'Library::IEventsSink::OnSomethingHappened' only by calling convention   
Error   2   error C2695: 'MyEventsSink::SomeTest': overriding virtual function differs from 'Library::IEventsSink::SomeTest' only by calling convention
```

I tried goggling regarding this error but I could not figure it out.

Here is what I am doing , I have a managed C# dll class library which is being consumed by a native C++ application. The code for C# interface is as follows and the implemention of this interface is in C++.

The C# code is

```
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("fdb9e334-fae4-4ff5-ab16-d874a910ec3c")]
    public class IEventsSinkImpl : IEventsSink
    {
        public void OnSomethingHappened()
        {
            //Doesnt matter what goes on here - atleast for now
        }

        public void SomeTest(IEventsSink snk)
        {
            //When this is called - it will call the C++ code
            snk.OnSomethingHappened();
        }
    }//end method
```

And its implemetation code in C++ is

```
class MyEventsSink : public Library::IEventsSink
{
public:
    MyEventsSink() {}
    ~MyEventsSink() {}

    virtual HRESULT OnSomethingHappened()
    {
        std::cout << "Incredible - it worked";
    }

    virtual HRESULT SomeTest(IEventsSink* snk)
    {
        //Doesnt matter this wont be called
    }

};
```

Apparently during the build process VS2010 complains of the above mentioned errors. Any suggestions on how I could resolve those errors.

Comment: You got the correct answer to your previous question.  Why are you not using it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Managed Dll and Native C++ - Is it possible to call consumer methods through a managed DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446855/c-sharp-managed-dll-and-native-c-is-it-possible-to-call-consumer-methods-thr)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `__stdcall` calling convention:

```
virtual HRESULT __stdcall OnSomethingHappened()
```

Normally, C++ uses the `__cdecl` calling convention, where the caller removes the parameters from the stack after the call. Most Windows API functions including COM use `__stdcall` where the callee removes the parameters from the stack.

Obviously, when you override a virtual function, the calling convention of both functions must be the same, because the function call is resolved at runtime.

Comment: This is correct and all, but why should he do this? What is `__stdcall` and why does it fix the problem? As it stands, you're just presenting him with "magic code".

Comment: There's a lot more to it, the class also has to implement IUnknown.  He already got the correct answer on his previous question.